# Menu page with minimum capability as 'Subscriber' doesn't allow 'Admin' to access it?

Tags: plugin-development, menus, user-roles, capabilities

I've added a separate menu page (an object page) with minimum access level required as 'Subscriber'. I'm doing this because I'm registering new users and they'll be 'Subscribers' with an extra capability to edit a section that my plugin creates. So I want them to be able to see this menu as well. I created my menu page as follows:

`add_object_page('Personal Section', 'Personal Section', 'subscriber', 'personal-section', 'personal_section_fn');`

Now when I log in with the subscriber credentials, I'm able to see this menu, but I'm not able to see it when logged in as Admin. Am I doing something wrong here?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Any reason you're using `add_object_page()`, rather than `add_settings_page()`, or - if you must - `add_menu_page()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`subscriber` is [a role, not a capability](http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities). Use a capability to manage access, e.g. `read`.

To understand the difference better install [Justin Tadlock’s plugin Members](http://justintadlock.com/archives/2009/09/17/members-wordpress-plugin).
For the **subscriber** role you get a list of capabilities like this:

[image]

The **administrator** role in contrast:

[image]

Comment: @Chip I'm using 'add_object_page' because I want my menu to appear along with the other menus, it the same list as Posts, Comments etc. because my custom post shows up there and this menu works with those custom posts. 'add_menu_page' adds it as a separate menu item.  @toscho I'm adding a new custom capability to the Subscriber role, I will use this capability to allow the user to see this custom menu page I'm creating (if <cap> show else don't show). But for that I need to create this menu with a minimum access level as subscriber so that subscribers are always allowed to see this menu.

Comment: @Rutwick Gangurde Roles are **not** access levels. Such a thing does not exist in WordPress. Don’t see these roles as hierarchies, they are just **names** for predefined sets of capabilities.

Comment: @toscho Ok... my bad! Say, I create a new custom role 'tester', with read capability and a custom capability, 'test'. I just want the users under this role to see the menu page I'm creating above when they log in! So what minimum capability do I mention when adding the menu page? I said subscribers above because subscriber role has only 'Read' capability, and so does my new role with a custom capability. I hope now I'm clear with my question!

Comment: @Rutwick Gangurde You have to assign the capability to all roles that should be able to see the menu. But **read** should do it. All roles have this capability.

Comment: @toscho Thanks a lot! I assigned the custom capability 'test' for creating the menu page and I assigned it to 'administrator' role also, and bingo, it worked! Now both my custom role and admin can see that menu page! Thanks all for your help!

Comment: The whole idea behind this was, the admin should be able to see all the sections on the custom menu page 'Sections', and the users with the custom role 'test', should only be able to see only their 'Sections' when logged in.